# Function to check string for a-z

Tags: vba, function, excel

I want to :

- cycle down a specific column `H` (starting from `H4`), and
- for each cell along that column, call a function to see if it is true (then do something ) or if it comes out false (do something else).

I'm getting runtime error `***invalid use of property***` on `Call Isletter`.

```
Sub IfBlank()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim Isletter As Range

Set Rng = Range("H4:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each MyCell In Rng
Call Isletter
If Isletter(MyCell.Value) = True Then
'do nothing
End If
If Isletter(MyCell.Value) = False Then
 MyCell.Value = "-"
 End If

 Next MyCell
End Sub

Public Function IsLetter(MyCell As String) As Boolean

    Dim intPos As Integer
    For intPos = 1 To Len(MyCell)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(MyCell, intPos, 1))
            Case 33 To 127
                Isletter = True
            Case Else
                Isletter = False
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Correction: Isletter not Isletter2

Comment: Please [edit] your post, people might not read the comments ;-) there's also a typo, `Fasle` -> `False`.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you getting any specific error? On which line? Please flesh up your question.

Comment: Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: Is MyCell a string or a range? It can't be used as both. Probably easier to test if you take the code from IsLetter and put it into IfBlank than to call it. Are you wanting to test MyCell.Value?

Comment: Remove the line `Call Isletter` it is not needed as the function is called in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

The code below

- uses a variant array (which is much quicker than a range loop) to process each value from H4:Hx
- uses a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) that can quickly check if at least one character in the string is alphabetic. If so blanks that string.

Thos line `Range("H4:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Value2 = X` writes the changed array back to the range.

*code*

```
Sub IfBlank()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long

Dim objRegex As Object
X = Range("H4:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Value2

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With objRegex
         .IgnoreCase = True
         .Pattern = "[a-z]"

         For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
            If .test(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then X(lngCnt, 1) = vbNullString
         Next
    End With

Range("H4:H" & Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Value2 = X

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsLetter` function has non optional argument `(MyCell As String)` so you must always pass this argument and must be string.

```
If IsLetter(MyCell.Value) = True Then
  'do something
Else
  'do something else  
End If
```

Comment: this did help me get through the function issue. thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The "Call isletter" shouldn't be there
That part of the code should look like this instead

```
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If Isletter(MyCell.Value) = True Then
     'do nothing
    else
     MyCell.Value = "-"
    End If

Next MyCell
```

Your "IsLetter" function is going to cause trouble.  ASCII 127 is "delete"

Also, only ASCII 65-90 and 97 - 122 are letters.  Is this supposed to include numeric and special characters?

if not, then it should look more like this

```
Public Function IsLetter(MyCell As String) As Boolean

Dim intPos As Integer
For intPos = 1 To Len(MyCell)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(Ucase(MyCell), intPos, 1))
        Case 90 To 122
            Isletter = True
            Exit Function
        Case Else
            Isletter = False
            Exit For
    End Select
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I do want to include numeric and special characters but the code seems to cycling through every character without stopping once it verified it is true. Eg (Microsoft Excel) The code reads Microsoft but once "SPACE" is read, it returns the code FALSE then putting "-". I would like it to read "M" then stop and move to the next cell.

Comment: Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122 is what I need, the issue is that I would like to the code to stop once ANY part of this case is met. even if the cell is has a bunch of spaces and one letter it should return true.

Comment: James, I edited my answer to give you what you want.  You just add the "Exit Function" line to the code and it will break out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me. I wanted to know what if I had no If statements? How would you get the funtion Isletter to work?

Comment: For Each MyCell In Rng
    Isletter

Next MyCell